# How to insert UIImagePickerController inside UITabbarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app that is based on `UITabBarController`. It has 3 tabs. In the first tab(default when app is launched), `UIImagePickerController` will be shown to select a album. But the problem is: `TabBar` will be covered by `UIImagePickerController`. How to insert `UIImagePickerController` inside the `UITabBarController`? Help is much appreciated. Here is my code:

// the first tab's `viewController.m`

```
- (void)loadView 
{

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:NO];
    [imagePicker release];

}
```

After try again, I modify some code as follows, the tab bar can be shown, but it couldn't been clicked. how to do?

```
- (void)loadView 
{

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:NO];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(imagePicker.view.frame.origin.x,        
                             imagePicker.view.frame.origin.y, 
                             imagePicker.view.frame.size.width, 
                             imagePicker.view.frame.size.height-self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height);

    imagePicker.view.frame = rect;
    [imagePicker.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
    [imagePicker release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of presenting it as a modal view controller, just add it's view to your current view controller:

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
    [imagePicker release];    
}
```

Don't forget to make adjustments to the frame if needed.

Comment: Thanks. But it will show a completely white screen with no blue bar.

Comment: Have you defined the frame and the sourceType for the picker?

Comment: I add the sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary, and CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
    imagePicker.view.frame = rect; before addSubView.  but nothing is happen.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `loadView` is being called? Maybe put an `NSLog` statement in there.

Comment: Yes, loadView is called. If mark the line:[self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view], ImagePickerController will be shown, but the TabBar will be covered.